# Iterate in O(n^2 / 2) a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a dictionary :

```
d = {'a':0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
```

I would like to make a new dictionary that computes the product of values of `d` and `d`.

This is the result I need :

```
d = {'a#a': 0, 'a#b': 0, 'a#c': 0, 'b#b' : 1, 'b#c': 2, 'c#c': 4}
```

However I do not want to have this result :

```
d = {'a#a': 0, 'a#b': 0, 'a#c': 0, 'b#a' : 0, 'b#b' : 1, 'b#c': 2, 'c#a': 0, 'c#b': 2, 'c#c': 4}
```

Because `c#a` was already computed by `a#c` for instance.

If this was an array or a list, I would do something like

```py
res = []
t = [0, 1, 2]

for i in range(len(t):
    for j in range(i):
        res.append(t[i] * t[j])
```

How can I do something similar but with dictionaries?

Answer (score 3):

Python comes with batteries included, but the cleanest way isn't always obvious. You already have the function you want built in to `itertools`.

Try this:

```
import itertools
result = {f'{k1}#{k2}': d[k1]*d[k2]
   for k1, k2 in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(d, 2)}
```

`itertools.combinations` gives you all pairs with no duplication, `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` gives you the unique pairs including the ones where the keys are the same.

Output:

```
>>> print(result)
{'a#a': 0, 'a#b': 0, 'a#c': 0, 'b#b': 1, 'b#c': 2, 'c#c': 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict comprehension for this:

```
dd = {f'{k}#{l}': v*w for k,v in d.items() for l,w in d.items() if k<=l}
>>> {'a#a': 0, 'a#b': 0, 'a#c': 0, 'b#b': 1, 'b#c': 2, 'c#c': 4}
```

EDIT:
If you want the result sorted by item apparition in d:

```
d = {'b': 0, 'a': 1, 'c': 2}
dd = {f'{k}#{l}': v*w 
      for i,(k,v) in enumerate(d.items()) 
      for j,(l,w) in enumerate(d.items()) 
      if i<=j}
>>> {'b#b': 0, 'b#a': 0, 'b#c': 0, 'a#a': 1, 'a#c': 2, 'c#c': 4}
```

Comment: That doesn't work if key `'a'` comes after `'b'` though.

Comment: What do you mean ? It works perfectly for me even if `a` comes after `b`

Comment: I mean you won't see `'b#a'` in the output dictionary, if in the input `'a'` comes after `'b'` because the condition fails.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)?

```
{f"{k1}#{k2}": d[k1] * d[k2] for k1 in d for k2 in d if k1 <= k2}
```

Or, if you prefer traditional style

```
result = {}
for k1 in d:
    for k2 in (k for k in d if k >= k1):
        result[f"{k1}#{k2}"] = d[k1] * d[k2]
```

The latter form uses a generator so it wouldn't create a separate list of keys every time.

Note: it won't work if the keys aren't comparable (i.e. not integers, strings or so), so you should use for example `if hash(k1) < hash(k2)` (it will work for all types of keys, since dictionary keys are required to be hashable, but the order of the keys may not be intuitive).

Comment: As @Austin notes in another answer, both of these will not respect the original sorting of the keys, so `a#b` will replace `b#a` even if `b` was inserted before `a`.

Comment: @Acorn The OP probably does not need to keep the order, he just wants that each pair of different keys were in the result only once (i.e. either `a#b` or `b#a` but not both).

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools to get the combinations and form the dictionary!

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>>
>>> d
{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1}
>>> combinations(d.keys(),2) # this returns an iterator
<itertools.combinations object at 0x1065dc100>
>>> list(combinations(d.keys(),2)) # on converting them to a list 
[('a', 'c'), ('a', 'b'), ('c', 'b')]
>>> {"{}#{}".format(v1,v2): (v1,v2) for v1,v2 in combinations(d.keys(),2)} # form a dict using dict comprehension, with "a#a" as key and a tuple of two values.
{'a#c': ('a', 'c'), 'a#b': ('a', 'b'), 'c#b': ('c', 'b')}
>>> {"{}#{}".format(v1,v2): d[v1]*d[v2] for v1,v2 in combinations(d.keys(),2)}
{'a#c': 0, 'a#b': 0, 'c#b': 2} # form the actual dict with product as values
>>> {"{}#{}".format(v1,v2):d[v1]*d[v2] for v1,v2 in list(combinations(d.keys(),2)) + [(v1,v1) for v1 in d.keys()]} # form the dict including the self products!
{'a#c': 0, 'a#b': 0, 'a#a': 0, 'b#b': 1, 'c#c': 4, 'c#b': 2}
```

Or as simple as pointed by Duncan,

```
>>> from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
>>> {"{}#{}".format(v1,v2): d[v1]*d[v2] for v1,v2 in combinations_with_replacement(d.keys(),2)}
{'a#c': 0, 'a#b': 0, 'a#a': 0, 'b#b': 1, 'c#c': 4, 'c#b': 2}
```

Answer (score -1):

`itertools` for fun:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

letter_pairs, number_pairs = (combinations_with_replacement(l, r=2) for l in zip(*d.items()))
result = {letters: number 
          for letters, number in zip(map('#'.join, letter_pairs), 
                                     (a * b for a, b in number_pairs))}

print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'a#a': 0, 'a#b': 0, 'a#c': 0, 'b#b': 1, 'b#c': 2, 'c#c': 4}
```